# Warm starting QP solver in CPLEX

Tags: cplex, quadratic-programming

I'm trying to figure out how to warm start the quadratic programming solver(s) for CPLEX. I am specifically interested in warm starting the QP solver for nonconvex quadratic programs terminating at first-order stationary points.

I believe the [start()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.InitialInterface-class.html) function should do this, but I can't figure out how to have the solver use the starting data.

```
def setproblemdata(p):
    p.objective.set_sense(p.objective.sense.minimize)

    target = p.parameters.optimalitytarget.values
    p.parameters.optimalitytarget.set(target.first_order)

    p.linear_constraints.add(rhs=[20.0, 30.0], senses="LL")

    obj = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
    ub = [40.0, cplex.infinity, cplex.infinity]
    cols = [[[0, 1], [-1.0, 1.0]],
            [[0, 1], [1.0, -3.0]],
            [[0, 1], [1.0, 1.0]]]

    p.variables.add(obj=obj, ub=ub, columns=cols,
                names=["one", "two", "three"])

    qmat = [[[0, 1, 2], [0.0, -1.0, 0.0]],
        [[0, 1, 2], [-1.0, 2.0, -1.0]],
        [[0, 1, 2], [0.0, -1.0, 2.0]]]

    p.objective.set_quadratic(qmat)

    p.parameters.advance.set(2)
    s = p.start.status


def qpex1():
    p = cplex.Cplex()
    setproblemdata(p)
    p.start.set_start([], [], [40.000000, 24.333333, 10.666667], [], [], [])
    p.solve()
```

My starting point is at the first-order stationary point CPLEX outputs, but I am finding it not responding to my input.

Comment: One possible way: if you formulate the first order conditions, you end up with a MIP. You can use MIPSTART with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, the [Cplex.start.set_start](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.InitialInterface-class.html#set_start) method calls [CPXcopystart](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/cpxapi/copystart.html) in the C Callable Library. From the documentation of `CPXcopystart` it says:

> Starting information is not applicable to the barrier optimizer nor to
>   the mixed integer optimizer (MIP).

So, it is expected that the starting information is ignored in your test program above.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reference. Are you aware of any nonconvex (bounded) QP solvers that allow warm starts?